# How to change sorting rule of dirset/fileset in Ant sort task

Tags: maven, sorting, ant

I am using Ant and Maven to build and deploy my war files.
It's mostly working but part of deployment is to update the database based on files stored in directories named like this:

0.0.1
0.0.2
...
0.0.9
...
1.4.5
....
1.4.11
...

Of course this needs to be done in order from earlier to newer version of script for example 1.4.5 needs to be done before 1.4.11

I know you can do sort by using antcontrib on a fileset but the problem is that it does sorts alphabetically and I would like to do it numerically. Is there some way?

PS.I guess I could sort strings in Javascript using the script tag but before I try to implement that would like to know is there any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [sorted resource collection](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#sort) and sort by name, f.e. :

given :

```
c:\tryme
+-0.0.1
+-0.0.2
+-0.0.3
```

snippet with simple echo :

```
<project>

<pathconvert property="sorted" pathsep="${line.separator}">
 <sort>
  <dirset dir="c:\tryme" />
  <name/>
 </sort>
</pathconvert>

<echo>$${sorted} => ${sorted}</echo>

</project>
```

output :

```
[echo] ${sorted} => c:\tryme
[echo] c:\tryme\0.0.1
[echo] c:\tryme\0.0.2
[echo] c:\tryme\0.0.3
```

**EDIT**

Note that you might get unexpected results when sorting dirnames (and more generally strings) with numbers, as an ASCII sort is used that does not consider the numeric values within the strings. You might use another comparator (f.e. [Alphanum Algorithm](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html)) with your own filterchain, see ant manual [FilterChains and Filterreaders](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html).

Comment: I don't believe this sorts 1.4.5 before 1.4.11

Comment: @mat007 Of course, it uses default ASCII sort, edited my answer with some details